# How to use a Dataframe content as function input?

Tags: python, pandas

Evening Mates,

I want to know if is there anyway of using the a table content as input for a function without having to get each individual value.

Like unpacking a table as we do for tuples. Kinda function(*(tuple)) but instead of using a tuple, i want to use a single row of a dataframe, where each column will be used as a sequential input.

What i'm trying to do is:

```
# Table that has a single row with name and age
table_content = table.loc[table['ID'] == id]

# I want to cast it like this
function_for_name_and_age(table_content)

# Without having to do
table_content_name = table_content['Name'].values(0)
table_content_age = table_content['Age'].values(0)

function_for_name_and_age(table_content_name, table_content_age )

'''
```

Comment: It's not clear what you try to accomplish.

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos I edited the question, so i hope now it's a bit more clearer.

Comment: If you want a row as a tuple to pass as an arg to a function?

tuple_row = df.to_records(index=False)[0]

Comment: Gotta say, you solve it mate. Thanks!

Comment: @user3249641 can you answer this topic so i can turn you as the answer one mate? So we can help the others in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a df row to a tuple.

```
import pandas as pd


table = pd.DataFrame([[1, "Tom", 36, 3], [2, "Bob", 30, 2]], columns=["ID", "Name", "Age", "Children"])
table_content = table.loc[table["ID"] == 1]

_id, name, age, children = table_content.to_records(index=False)[0]


def function_for_name_and_age(table_name: str, table_age: int) -> tuple:
    return table_name, table_age


print(function_for_name_and_age(name, age))
```